# Mixing two javascript code

Tags: javascript

I try desperately for hours and hours to get this 2 little script working without success . If I use them just like that, no one work but if I include only one no problem. So the issue is not with the code itself but with a conflict when code are used together. I tried dozen of combination and also by adding some else statement but without luck too.

---

### CODE 1

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function on_my_form_loaded(event) {
if (event=='reserve')
var mobile_number_param = document.getElementById('mobile_number_param');
mobile_number_param.value = "[cb:userdata field="cb_myfield" user="#me" /]";
mobile_number_param.readOnly = true;
var email = document.getElementById('email');
email.readOnly = true;
var first = document.getElementById('first');
first.readOnly = true;
var last = document.getElementById('last');
last.readOnly = true;
}
// ]]></script>
```

---

### CODE 2

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function on_my_form_loaded(event) {
if (event=='show_cart')
document.getElementById('empty_cart_block').style.display='none';
}
// ]]></script>
```

Unfortunately I'm not a coder...Someone have a suggestion please ?

Comment: Hard to tell whats going on with no indentation, no brackets for `if` statements...

Comment: Did you try debugging it ?

Comment: I think the first one is incorrectly written and should have everything after the `if` line enclosed in another set of curly braces. Then move lines 3 and 4 of the second block between the now two closing curly braces of the first block.

Comment: @Dany Y: it's called "Random Changes Driven Development", it doesn't imply using any debugger

Comment: After stating they are not a coder I would assume they don't know how to operate a debugger.

Comment: @GCATNM: Sorry, where is that statement?

Comment: Got edited out by someone else than the OP - no idea why someone would do that.

Comment: @GCATNM: Oh, wow, I see it. User 'Stedy' removed it. That is ***not cool***, I've put it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move them both into the same function. `on_my_form_loaded` and then use an if else to determine which chunk of code should execute. Like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function on_my_form_loaded(event) {
    if (event=='show_cart')
    {
        document.getElementById('empty_cart_block').style.display='none';
    }
    else if (event=='reserve')
    {
        var mobile_number_param = document.getElementById('mobile_number_param');
        mobile_number_param.value = "[cb:userdata field="cb_myfield" user="#me" /]";
        mobile_number_param.readOnly = true;
        var email = document.getElementById('email');
        email.readOnly = true;
        var first = document.getElementById('first');
        first.readOnly = true;
        var last = document.getElementById('last');
        last.readOnly = true;
    }
}

// ]]></script>
```

If the event is `show_cart` then the first chuck of code will run. If the event is `reverse` then the second chunk of code will run.

Comment: work great...many thank! In fact I think I tried this code but I was unable to get working. I had probably forget some brackets...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function on_my_form_loaded(event) {
    if (event=='reserve') {
        var mobile_number_param = document.getElementById('mobile_number_param');
        mobile_number_param.value = "[cb:userdata field="cb_myfield" user="#me" /]";
        mobile_number_param.readOnly = true;
        var email = document.getElementById('email');
        email.readOnly = true;
        var first = document.getElementById('first');
        first.readOnly = true;
        var last = document.getElementById('last');
        last.readOnly = true;
    }
    else if (event=='show_cart') {
        document.getElementById('empty_cart_block').style.display='none';
    }
}
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function on_my_form_loaded(event) {
    if (event=='reserve') {
        var mobile_number_param = document.getElementById('mobile_number_param');
        mobile_number_param.value = "[cb:userdata field="cb_myfield" user="#me" /]";
        mobile_number_param.readOnly = true;
        var email = document.getElementById('email');
        email.readOnly = true;
        var first = document.getElementById('first');
        first.readOnly = true;
        var last = document.getElementById('last');
        last.readOnly = true;
    }

    else if (event=='show_cart') {
        document.getElementById('empty_cart_block').style.display='none';
    }
}
// ]]></script>
```

Did you want it?

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to handle this, but try using a switch statement:

```
function on_my_form_loaded(event) {
    switch (event) {
    case "reserve":
        var mobile_number_param = document.getElementById('mobile_number_param');
        mobile_number_param.value = "[cb:userdata field="cb_myfield" user="#me" /]";
        mobile_number_param.readOnly = true;
        var email = document.getElementById('email');
        email.readOnly = true;
        var first = document.getElementById('first');
        first.readOnly = true;
        var last = document.getElementById('last');
        last.readOnly = true;
        break;
    case "show_cart":
        document.getElementById('empty_cart_block').style.display = 'none';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: To whoever downvotes the best answer so far while staying incognito - if there is indeed something wrong with it (which I don't see), giving your reasons for doing so could help improve it and make it more useful than you think it is right now.